# Inverse of the product of fractional ideals

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions and $\mathfrak M,\mathfrak N$ fractional ideals, i.e. non-zero finitely generated $R$-submodules of $K$.

$$\mathfrak M^{-1}=\{x\in K: x\mathfrak M\subseteq R\}$$

Then

> $$(\mathfrak M\mathfrak N)^{-1}=\mathfrak M^{-1}\mathfrak N^{-1}.$$

For the inclusion "$\supseteq$".

Suppose that $\alpha_i,\beta_j$  are finite sets of generators  for $\mathfrak N^{-1},\mathfrak M^{-1}$ respectively.

Then $$\alpha_i\beta_j\mathfrak M\mathfrak N\subseteq \alpha_iR\mathfrak N=\alpha_i\mathfrak N\subseteq R.$$  Thus $\alpha_i\beta_j\in (\mathfrak M\mathfrak N)^{-1}$. This prove the inclusion "$\supseteq$".

Thanks for any suggestion for the reverse inclusion.

Comment: No need to assume the fractional ideals finitely generated in order to show "$\supseteq$": If $x\in\mathfrak M^{-1}$ and $y\in\mathfrak N^{-1}$ then $x\mathfrak M\subseteq R$ and $y\mathfrak N\subseteq R$, so $xy(\mathfrak M\mathfrak N)=(x\mathfrak M)(y\mathfrak N)\subseteq R$. The other containment I don't think is true, in general.

Comment: @user26857; help me for "$\subseteq$"; thanks. If $\mathfrak M$ is finitely generated then  $\mathfrak M^{-1}$ is finitely generated.

Comment: As I said, that does not necessarily hold; see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195731/examples-of-fractional-ideals-whose-inverse-does-not-commute-with-the-product). (I'm convinced that $\mathfrak M$ finitely generated does not imply $\mathfrak M^{-1}$ finitely generated, unless the ring is noetherian.)

Comment: In addition, if $R$ is a dedekind ring then this is obvious, because the set of fractional ideals is a abelian group. 
If we ignore this, do not know how would a proof of this. Thank you.

Comment: Gracias, lo que pasa es que no sé como hacer esa otra inclusión; aún en el caso de dominios de Krull.